# ODBC connection to Netezza from dotnet core 3.1 container

Tags: .net-core, containers, netezza, unixodbc

Need to buid a microservice that runs on dotnet core 3.1 (customer constraint) and connects to a Netezza backend.

I've managed to craft a `Dockerfile` that allows the container to be built and the code to run, after several trial/error efforts.

But I've hit a wall: I use a connection string with all the connection parameters but, when I try to run my code, I get the following exception:

```
System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException (0x80131937): ERROR [HY000B�H�d5Serv���p�U] [unixODBC]Server and/or port attributes are empty��d �
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.HandleError(OdbcHandle hrHandle, RetCode retcode)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnectionHandle..ctor(OdbcConnection connection, OdbcConnectionString constr, OdbcEnvironmentHandle environmentHandle)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnectionOpen..ctor(OdbcConnection outerConnection, OdbcConnectionString connectionOptions)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.Open()
```

I've enabled `DebugLogging=true` in `/etc/odbcinst.ini` and on the generated log I found that the connection string is being truncated:

```
...
SQLDriverConnectW:  entering    conn = 0x4317BFE0
    SQLDriverConnectInternal:   entering    conn = 0x4317BFE0
    SQLDriverConnectInternal:       nDriverCompletion=0, connStrIn='(D;'
readDSNConfig:   newDSN = 1, File = /usr/local/etc/odbc.ini, Section = NetezzaSQL
readDSNConfig:   Server = 
readDSNConfig:   Database = 
readDSNConfig:   Schema = 
readDSNConfig:   Port = 5480
readDSNConfig:   ReadOnly = 0
readDSNConfig:   BitOneZero = 0
readDSNConfig:   FastSelect = 0
readDSNConfig:   StripCrLf = 0
readDSNConfig:   LegacySQLTables = 0
readDSNConfig:   NumericAsChar = 0
readDSNConfig:   ShowSystemTables = 0
readDSNConfig:   securityLevel = preferredUnSecured
readDSNConfig:   Security level requested = 0
readDSNConfig:   CA certificate used = 
readDSNConfig:   LoginTimeout = 0
readDSNConfig:   QueryTimeout = 0
readDSNConfig:   DateFormat = 1
readDSNConfig:   loadMaxErrors = 1
readDSNConfig:   loadRoundFraction = 0
readDSNConfig:   User ID = 
readDSNConfig:   Workstation Name = 
readDSNConfig:   Application Name = 
readDSNConfig:   Acct String = 
readDSNConfig:   Program Info = 
readDSNConfig:   IgnoreFloatingPointTruncation = 0
    Conn_connect:   Entering    do_password = 0
Connection Error: Function = 'Conn_connect', Line = 1504, State = 'HY000', number = 33, Msg = 'Server and/or port attributes are empty'
...
```

I've tried to use a DSN or to change the order of the values in the connection string. For instance,I started the string with a semicolon and in the log changed to show this: `connStrIn='(;'`. If I leave the connection string blank or make a invalid one, dotnet complaints with `System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException (0x80131937): ERROR [IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified` so, I can tell that the "Driver" or "Dsn" parts are being used at first, but seems that are not being passed/received properly by the driver.
I've also created a `[NetezzaSQL]` section with the connection parameters on the file `odbc.ini` but here it fails with an *Invalid user ID* error (in spite that i've provided it with the key "Username"). Nevertheless having a file based DSN is not appropriate as credentials can't be stored in the container for obvious security reasons.

If I access the container and try the `nzodbcsql` with the connection params or a defined DSN, it connects just fine and allows me to run queries happily.

The driver version I'm using is `Release 7.2.0.0 [Build 40845]`.
The NPS version is: `11.02.0001 Release 11.2.1.0 [Build 30]`.

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-bionic AS base

USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y -qq install make gcc libc6-i386 zlib1g unixodbc unixodbc-dev


COPY netezza.tar.gz /opt/

RUN tar -zxvf /opt/netezza.tar.gz -C /opt/
RUN /opt/netezza/linux64/unpack -f /usr/local/nz

RUN sed -i 's/DebugLogging=false/DebugLogging=true/g' /etc/odbcinst.ini
COPY .odbc.ini /etc/odbc.ini

RUN echo '/usr/local/nz/lib' >> /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu.conf
RUN echo '/usr/local/nz/lib64' >> /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu.conf
RUN ldconfig
RUN ln -s /usr/local/nz/bin64/nzodbcsql /usr/local/bin/nzodbcsql

USER 1001
ENV PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/nz/bin64/:
ENV NZ_ODBC_INI_PATH=/etc/
ENV ODBCINI=/etc/odbc.ini
WORKDIR /app


FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-bionic AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["testprg.csproj", "appsettings.json", "appsettings.Development.json", "Program.cs", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore "testprg.csproj"
#COPY . . 
WORKDIR /src
RUN dotnet build "testprg.csproj" -c Release -o /app
FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "testprg.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
workdir /app
COPY --from=publish /app .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "testprg.dll"]
```

And here is my test program:

```
using System;
using System.Data.Odbc;

namespace testprg
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           String connString = "Driver={NetezzaSQL};Servername=*****;Port=5480;Database=*****;Username=****;Password=*****";
           OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(connString.Normalize());
           
           OdbcCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
           cmd.CommandText="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TEST_TABLE;";
           cmd.CommandType=System.Data.CommandType.Text;
           Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
           try {
               Console.WriteLine(conn.ConnectionString);
               conn.Open();
               OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
               while (reader.Read()) {
                   Console.WriteLine(reader["COUNT"].ToString());
               }
           } catch (OdbcException e) {
               Console.WriteLine(e);
           }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the above debug log we see /usr/local/etc/odbc.ini is the location of the ini file which the Netezza driver is trying to read & it doesn't have the required fields. Because you are able to connect using nzodbcsql, driver is able to talk to NPS but driver manger i.e. UnixODBC might not able to recognize it. UnixODBC, most of the time reads from $HOME directory that too a hidden file .odbc.ini. Please verify if the installed Netezza ODBC Driver is recognized by UnixODBC. You can do so by checking the ini configuration using the below commands. Also try to connect database using isql cli (provided by unixODBC).

```
odbcinst -j
odbcinst -q -s -n NZSQL
odbcinst -q -d -n NetezzaSQL
isql NZSQL username password -v
```

If you are still unsuccessful paste me the output of the above commands.

Regards,
Samir.

Comment: Thanks Samir!!! Among the multiple tests I've made, I've changed the location of the odbc.ini file or had an identical copy at `/etc`, `/usr/local/etc` and at `~/.odbc.ini`. Every test with the same result: The error I keep getting is `[unixODBC]Server and/or port attributes are empty`.

Comment: Here are the outputs of the commands you gave me: [Box link](https://ibm.box.com/s/73ht8vyldl4wl8iug0w6084fmed56q2j)

Answer (score 0):

Thenks to @[Samir-Sayyed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2239409/samir-sayyed) who helped me resolve this issue offline. What solved the issue was to add the following to the Dockerfile:

```
++RUN sed -i 's/UnicodeTranslationOption=utf8/UnicodeTranslationOption=utf16/g' /etc/odbcinst.ini
```

The reason is that .net's ODBC dll assumes that the code pages is utf-16 in Linux.